# Change pointer to an array that is contained in a struct using inline assembly ia32

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

So I have this code in C, basically is a struct that contains a pointer to an array and a function that changes the value of the array in the index 0

```
typedef struct archivo
{
    unsigned char *info;
} FILE;

void funct(FILE *arch) {
  arch->info[0] = 'b';
}
```

So I have to translate the funct function to inline assembly. I tried doing the following

```
void funct(FILE *arch) {
   _asm {
     mov eax, 0
     mov ebx, arch.info[eax]
     mov ecx, [ebx]
     mov ecx, 'b'
  }
}
```

But when I print the output, the info continues to have the same value.
So I try the output with the following code

```
void funct(ARCHIVO *arch)
{
    printf("\n--%c--\n", arch->info[0]);

    _asm {
         mov eax, 0
         mov ebx, arch.info[eax]
         mov ecx, [ebx]
         mov ecx, 'b'
      }

    printf("\n--%c--\n", arch->info[0]);
}
```

and I get as output

```
--P--

--P--
```

How can I manage to change the C array value in position 0?

Comment: "Change array that is contained in a struct" - There is no array in your `struct`. A pointer is not an array. And `char *` is not a pointer to array, but to `char`.

Comment: `mov ecx, 'b'` isn't going to write anything to `info`.  It's just going to assign a value to the ecx register.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd how can I change the info value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
void funct(FILE *arch) {
    _asm{
        mov eax, arch
        mov eax,[eax]archivo.info
        mov byte ptr [eax],'b'
    }
}
```

or better

```
__declspec(naked) void __fastcall funct2(FILE * /*arch*/) {
    _asm{
        mov eax,[ecx]archivo.info
        mov byte ptr [eax],'b'
        ret
    }
}
```